# Как правильно написать URL из разных типов данных {%url var:str %}

Tags: django

Я новичок в Django - не судите строго.

В шаблоне есть такой url, он работает:

```
{% url 'software:index' %}
```

Но мне нужно 'software' записать в качестве переменной, а именно `{{menu.name}}`

То есть как-то так `{% url menu.name:'index' %}`, где menu_name - переменная, а index - текст.

Не пойму синтаксиса как это сделать. Не получается слить оба значения в единое значение, чтобы Django правильно его прочёл.

Прошу помощи у экспертов.

Answer (score 1):

> В шаблоне есть такой url, он работает:
> `{% url 'software:index' %}`

Здесь используется так называемы namespace-адреса ([подробнее](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces)). А вы, если я правильно понял, хотите передать переменную в ваше представление. Тогда это не то, что вам нужно.

url-адреса с аргументами задаются в шаблоне в таком виде:

```html
{% url 'path_name' some_arg='some_value' %}
```

В кавычках вы задаете имя пути, а после передаете необходимые аргументы.

Для этого path или url должен иметь примерно такой вид:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('page/<some_arg>/', views.some_view, name='path_name'),
]
```

Вы также можете указывать Django только те типы передаваемых аргументов, которые вам нужны. Если вы хотите получать в качестве переменной только строку, исправьте предыдущий пример на это:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('page/<str:some_arg>/', views.some_view, name='path_name'),
]
```

Если вы хотите передать больше переменных, то разделите их в тэге шаблона пробелами:

```html
{% url 'path_name' some_arg='some_value' second_arg=2 %}
```

и не забудьте добавить эти аргументы в путь:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('page/<str:some_arg>/<int:second_arg>', views.some_view, name='path_name'),
]
```

Прочитайте подробнее о url-адресах и диспетчере url в [официальной документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/)

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, но мне действительно нужны namespace-адреса.
Именно в таком формате нужно:
{% url 'software:index' %}

Comment: Это не проблема) Вы также можете передать аргументы, используя синтаксис, описанный выше. `{% url 'software:index' menu_name=menu.name %}`

Comment: У меня этот кусок: 'software:index' - генерится динамически. Заранее я знаю только 'index', а что будет вместо 'software' заранее неизвестно. Поэтому вместо 'software' нужна переменная.

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, больше кода. Особенно, где вы хотите это использовать. Пока на ум приходит только посоветовать передавать url заранее из представления через контекст. Не хочу показаться тупым, но я не сильно понял где, как и для чего вы хотите это применить

Comment: Я делаю меню сайта.
Есть главное меню, и у каждого пункта главного меню - подменю.

Пункты главного меню хранятся в одной таблице SQL, пункты подменю - в другой (связаны через ForeignKey).
Соответственно во вьюшке я беру из SQL эти значения и передаю их в шаблон.

А в шаблоне URL как я писал ранее: `{% url 'software:index' %}`, где software заранее неизвестен и пишется переменной, а index известен и пишется просто текстом. Задачи слить вместе переменную и текст, чтобы {% url %} правильно прочитал 'namespace:url'.

Comment: Спасибо! В итоге сделал, как вы написали. Сначала просто недопонял ваше решение.